Is it possible to belong to two different homogenous groups for tukey-HSD
I want to start by saying I'm a beginner in statistical analysis, I'm learning for my thesis and I'm using the TIBCO Statistica software.
So basically what I did is cluster analysis and got 4 different clusters that I want to check the means for and if they are statistically different so I did ANOVA and I got p<0.05 across all the items.
so I wanted to do Tukey HSD to see how they differ from each other and to check homogenous groups. to my surprise the results for certain items (let's say the alcohol mean) gave that cluster 3 belongs to two different homogenous groups? I'm not sure how is that possible. Did I do something wrong?


It is absolutely possible. It means that Tukey HSD did not find a significant difference between the means of clusters 2 and 3, nor did it find significant differences between the means of clusters 3 and 1, 3 and 4, and 1 and 4. But it found significant differences between the means of clusters 2 and 1, and 2 and 4.
This in fact happens very frequently with 1-way ANOVA: you have an "intermediate" mean (in the middle) not too far from any of the extreme means, so that it then belongs to 2 groups.
Now, if a cluster belonged to 3 groups, that would be an issue...
